# Keep window.opener property across redirects

Tags: javascript, redirect

From my website, I open a login dialog in a new window:

```
window.open('mysite/Login/');
```

`mysite/Login/` automatically redirects me to the OAuth provider.
The OAuth provider does its hokey-pokey, and then redirects me back to to `mysite/Login/` with the valid credentials.

Now comes the tricky part: I want to tell the app (`window.opener`) that the login is ready.

I tried to return the following HTML in `mysite/Login`:

```
<html><script> 
    window.opener.MyApp.proceedAfterLogin()
</script></html>
```

But this throws the error

> Login:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyApp' of null

So `window.opener` is null. I think it is not preserved through the redirects; is this assumption correct? How can I still achieve the same result?

Can I put a JavaScript object into a cookie? (I don't think so, a cookie can only store text, right?)

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution would be to store the value as localStorage then retrieve when the OAuth is complete.

```
locationStorage.setItem('opener', JSON.stringify(window.opener));
```

Then once the OAuth is complete do.

```
window.opener = JSON.parse(locationStorage.opener);
```

Comment: You can not serialize/deserialize window object.